# Overlaying image with polygon shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, image, overlay

I am using QGIS and I'd like to know how I can make this kind of image overlay using as base a polygon shapefile of my city's blocks, just like in the following images.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 7):

1. Create a new layer, draw a polygon covering your area
2. Difference geoprocessing tool, with your polygon as input, and the blocks as Overlay. Set a dark grey or black symbol

Now you have a polygon with holes where your blocks are.

3. Create a new print layout
4. Add picture, your raster image
5. Add map, uncheck background to see the image through the holes.
   [image]